# Estimate the mean, variance and correlation separately to make off-diagonal elements of covariance matrix "identically distributed"?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, estimation, covariance

I have a $d$-dimensional data with $n$ observations. So the matrix for the dataset is $d\times n$. One possible way to fit the data is to assume that each column is a random sample from a multivariate normal distribution so I could use MLE or Bayesian method to estimate the mean vector and the covariance matrix.

**However, I am looking for a model to make the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix "identically distributed" -- that's the property I want.**

To better illustrate, my naive solution is to estimate the mean, variance and correlation separately. To be specific, I would like to assume that the means of each element in the random vector, $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_d$ are sampled from a distribution, for example, $F_1 = N(0, \sigma)$. And the standard deviation of each element, $\sigma_1^2, \dots, \sigma_d^2$ are also sampled from another distribution, say $F_2$. And in the correlations of each two elements, $r_{12}, r_{13}, \dots, r_{d(d-1)}$ are also sampled from a distribution $F_3$. Then I could use the dataset to estimate the three distribution separately. It seems that each of the three distribution has nothing to do with the other two. In particular, the covariance of element $i$ and $j$ from the random vector could be expressed as $\sigma_i\sigma_jr_{ij}$ where $\sigma_i, \sigma_j\sim F_2$ and $r_{ij}\sim F_3$ -- "identically distributed".

I know it sounds weird. But if I could model the dataset in this way, it would greatly faciliate my future analysis. Unfortunately, I could not find any reference regarding this method. The closest related reference I could find is about how a standard Wishart random matrix is generated -- by sampling $d$ independent $\chi^2$ variables and $\frac{d(d-1)}{2}$ independent standard normal variables. However, the off-diagonal elements of the covariance are no longer "identically distributed".

I was wondering whether my proposal plausible or is there a better way to make the off-diagonal elements "identically distributed"? Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: This is screaming XY problem, where you have some issue X that you think you can solve with Y, so you ask about Y instead of X. (This is common. I asked an XY problem last month, even.) Is there some X you want to solve?

Comment: Ah! I think the X problem is to find a model to make the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix "identically distributed". My Y is a possible solution and a illustration of what "identically distributed" means here but I don't know if it is theoretically correct.

Comment: @Dave I have revised my question. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: One issue is the the covariances may not be independent of each other or of the variances. Even if you remove the variance issue by looking at correlations, the correlations may not be independent of each other

Comment: @Henry Thank you Henry! Is it still practically acceptable to assume that the correlations are independent, just like what people assume for different independent variables in OLS regression?

Comment: As it stands, this looks like a Bayesian inference problem with prior distributions for all parameters. In Bayesian analysis, however, you need to *assume* "that each of the three distribution has nothing to do with the other two" - this isn't about how it "seems" (I suspect that this can't be identified from the data), it's about what kind of assumption you are willing to make. I'd say you can in principle just assume some $F_1, F_2, F_3$ and use an MCMC software to do the Bayesian analysis.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure about what you mean by "identically distributed off-diagonal elements" of the covariance matrix. Note that a matrix needs to fulfill certain conditions to be a valid correlation matrix, meaning that there needs to be a certain dependence structure among the $r_{ij}$ implied by $F_3$; so these $r_{ij}$ could technically be identically but not independently distributed. Maybe what you mean by "no longer identically distributed" is actually due to their dependence, not non-identity?

Comment: @Lewian Hi Lewain. Thank you for your comment! Yes, what I mean is actually due to their dependence. I should replace "identically" with "independent identically"... I am not sure whether my assumption above is plausible or not.

Comment: @Slangevar Due to the side conditions on correlation matrices (positive semidefinite) the different entries of it have to be dependent. Under independence you can't guarantee that you get a valid correlation matrix. So $F_3$ does need some dependence in order to generate valid correlation matrices.

Comment: @Lewian. Thank you Lewain. Is there any possible way around or approximate the correlation matrix with independent variables from a univariate distribution?

Comment: Quite frankly I don't think that's a promising objective. I don't really understand what you think you'd get out of this, however I believe that you should probably think about how to achieve what you ultimately want to achieve in different ways.